# Reduced delivery rate for mails with li-Domain?

Tags: email, spam, spam-prevention, email-spam

I am using AWS SES with a Liechtenstein domain, i.e. mail@service_name.li. I experience that my mails, account activation mails for users of my service, are often marked as spam by many mail providers.

I already checked what can be done to reduce spam rate but my quite specific question is: Does the fact that my mail domain is a Liechtenstein domain decrease deliverability?

Maybe someone has experience with the spam filtering methods of the bigger mail services and knows if that can be an issue. In that case, I would change the domain. If not, I will have to dig deeper to find the issues.

Comment: Off topic here, as not about programming. That said: Check how you send your emails. Valid MIME structure? Do you have DKIM, DMARC, SPF correctly configured? Run some emails through spam filters like spam assassin and check what they think of your content. Check the reputation of your sending IP address, e.g., with spamhaus. Get on the big providers' postmaster lists and sign up for feedback. If nothing helps, look for professional email delivery consulting. I like postmastery.